# hyperledger Composer use after depreciation

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Is it alright to use hyperledger composer for a professional project? Since its depreciated.
I have need to solve a problem which can be solved easily with hyperledger composer. My main question is Is it wise to use composer after its been depreciated. Will there be any deployment Issue or anything while im carrying out this project?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly advise you not to try to use hyperledger composer. It is end of life and the community has moved on, all that is left is the source code. The fabric client sdks and the new programming models on the chaincode side provide a much richer experience now and that is where you should focus your efforts.

Comment: What is the best method to get started with fabric ledger .. from chaincode to frontend?

Comment: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples and the hyperledger documentation is a good place to start for writing chaincode and client side code to interact with the chaincode. There is nothing fabric specific about writing front ends so there will be a multitude of code and docs around how to do that on the web.